# CSS/JS compression distorts the website template/look

Tags: joomla-3.4, javascript, css

My website has a score of 50/100 on pagespeed. I am trying to improve it's load speed. When i implement compression either via template (T3 template option)or JCH plugin the website completely looses it's look. It becomes distorted. Is there a way i could implement compression without affecting the website look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having used JCH a lot, I've found that either using the default settings, or pushing the caching to the maximum potential doesn't always work.

The first thing to do is, go to the **Automatic Settings Group** options, then:

- Disable all options under these settings
- Enable the options to **minify** CSS and JS
- Enable to option to **combine** CSS and JS
- Finally, enable the **GZip JavaScript and CSS** option

Make sure that after every instruction from the above list, you refresh your page to see if the site is working as normal and that you have no console log errors.

Once you notice the website change after an option change, keep it disabled.

Overall, it's one of those plugins that has to be tweaked for each individual site.

Comment: Actually i did as you recommended and wow..from 50/100 on pagespeed to 90/100. Thank man

Comment: @Paul - You're welcome. If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted so others who may have the same issue know it has been solved